# CSS transition not working on image

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, css-transitions

I have created a working transition for a div element, however, when I tried to apply the exact same method to an image class, it would not work. Instead of smoothly moving to the left it jumps to the left. The rotation transform animation does work, but not the left transition.

```
.firstimg{
width: 5%;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.turnedimg{
width: 5%;
cursor: pointer;
/*left: 12% !important;*/
position: absolute;

-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

I do not understand why the rotation works but the transition does not. How can I make the animations work? If anyone is interested, I am calling it through JQuery

```
$(".firstimg").toggleClass("turnedimg");
```

Comment: are you calling jquery on load?

Comment: Not so sure about this one, but it might be because the starting rotation point is not defined so you could put transform: rotate(0deg); on the .firstimg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image must have an initial value for 'left'

```
.firstimg{
width: 5%;
left: 0%;
cursor: pointer;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works ([working DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/bsbybar0/1)).

**BUT** you have to call `$(".firstimg").toggleClass("turnedimg");` on an event.

For example you could use `$( document ).ready();` or `$( selector ).click();`.

[Here](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) you can find ALL the JQuery events.

```js
//When page is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".firstimg").toggleClass("turnedimg");
  
  
  //On click
  $(".firstimg").click(function() {
    $(".firstimg").toggleClass("turnedimg");
  });
});
```

```css
.firstimg {
  width: 5%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.turnedimg {
  width: 5%;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*left: 12% !important;*/
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="firstimg" src="http://www.placehold.it/400/400">

<p>
Try to click the image
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, are you sure that you put the toggleClass inside the `$(document).ready()` ?

try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".firstimg").toggleClass("turnedimg");
});
```